# CSS Color overlay with background image

Tags: css

I am able to set a background image that covers a page but the green overlay does not work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: url("../images/worldmap.jpg") no-repeat rgba(0,255,0,.5);
    /*background-image: url("../images/worldmap.jpg");*/
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.overlay-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)),   url(https://www.nepalitrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/langtang-gosaikundaintro.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you may try this...

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
  background-size:cover;
  background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,255,0,.5);,rgba(0,255,0,.5);),url("../images/worldmap.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the url for the background image at the **end of the line**.

```
.page{
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,.5)), url('https://www.nepalitrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/langtang-gosaikundaintro.jpg') no-repeat;
        background: -webkit-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,.5)), url('https://www.nepalitrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/langtang-gosaikundaintro.jpg') no-repeat;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,.5)), url('https://www.nepalitrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/langtang-gosaikundaintro.jpg') no-repeat;
        background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,.5)), url('https://www.nepalitrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/langtang-gosaikundaintro.jpg') no-repeat;
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,.5)), url('https://www.nepalitrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/langtang-gosaikundaintro.jpg') no-repeat;
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,255,0,.5)), url('https://www.nepalitrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/langtang-gosaikundaintro.jpg') no-repeat;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
}
```